# Install GSL gem with Ruby 2.1 Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, gsl, ruby-2.1

I tried so many times, reading a lot for everywhere, but I can't install the gem with ruby 2.1, I'm currently using it with Ruby 2.0 + GSL 1.15 + GSL gem 1.15.3 + Debian 7.0 (wheezy)

Can someone share his recipe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we have a lot or an error?

Comment: Here's the log http://pastebin.com/Er6S0paU